# Struts2 with Google app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, struts2, javassist

I am trying to use Struts 2.5.2 with Google app engine (SDK version 1.9.40) using eclipse.

I have some sort of dependencies problem, between the asm library which is packed in Google's jars and javaassist which is required by Struts's prepare filter.

This is the exception I am getting on server startup:

> SEVERE: Unable to instrument javassist.ClassPool. Security
>   restrictions may not be entirely emulated. java.lang.RuntimeException
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(MethodVisitor.java:115)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:959)

It seems that javaassist 3.20 is not compatible with asm.

I cannot change asm version, since it is packed inside Google's sdk jars, but struts cannot use the prepare filter without javaassist...

Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:
It seems to me that it's a different problem than a question that was answered here, since my problem seems to be related to the ASM version that conflicts with JavaAssist and all solutions there did not work for me.

Comment: Some info - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4646.

Comment: @RomanC What do you mean "disable restrictions"?

Comment: I have tried changing the compiler level to 1.7, and I have the latest version of app engine SDK. I do not think it's the same problem as the other question here.